# Did google enabled multidex for their apps?

Tags: android

Google apps (for example gmail and playstore) might be having huge number of dependencies. Are they multidex enabled?

Comment: I suppose yes, why not?

Comment: All the android apps are constrained by this limitation including google's apps. This limitation is a **feature** born with **dex**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could actually check yourself if an app has multidex enabled.
Here's how I checked myself for the Play Store:

1. I went to apkmirror, and searched for Google Play Store. I opened the latest version, which is [this one right now](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-12-1-18-release/google-play-store-12-1-18-all-0-pr-216263519-android-apk-download/).
2. I downloaded the .apk file.
3. Rename the .apk to .zip, so you can open it with an archive tool.
4. Now unzip it (note: on Mac the default unarchiver utility did not work, I had to use Keka).
5. Have a look in the unzipped archive. If you see one `classes*.dex` file, it does not use multidexing. In the case of Google Play Store, I can see `classes.dex`, `classes2.dex`, ... `classes4.dex`. This means that the Play Store uses multidexing.